# Application on using JavaFX keeps on freezing even though I'm using Concurrent methods

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm trying to create an application in JavaFX that would retrieve data from my SQLITE database and display it. But even if I tried to use `Task` and `Platform.runLater()` and simulate a loading using `Thread.sleep()`, it would still freeze my app. I'm new to javaFX concurrency, but I'm trying to read the documentation ([JavaFXDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm)) but can't seem to find my solution.

> Here's the code

```java
    @FXML
    private void showAllData() throws SQLException, IOException {
        Task<Void> task = dataShowAsATask();
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    private Task<Void> dataShowAsATask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    try {
                        clearDataResultHolder();
                        dataResultHolder.getChildren().addAll(getArrayOfUserAsNode());

                        /* Simulate loading */
                        Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
                    } catch (SQLException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                });
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    private Node getUserAsANode(User user) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/org/prince/firstcrudtest/views/card/CardSkeleton.fxml"));
        Node data = fxmlLoader.load();
        CardSkeletonController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
        setController(controller, user);
        return data;
    }

    private AbstractList<Node> getArrayOfUserAsNode() throws SQLException, IOException {
        ArrayList<Node> result = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<User> data = dbNav.getAllData();
        for (User user : data) {
            result.addLast(getUserAsANode(user));
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void setController(CardSkeletonController controller, User user) {
        controller.setIdLabel(String.valueOf(user.getId()));
        controller.setUsernameLabel(user.getUserName());
        controller.setPasswordLabel(Arrays.toString(user.getPassword()));
        controller.setSaltLabel(Arrays.toString(user.getSalt()));
    }

    private void clearDataResultHolder() {
        dataResultHolder.getChildren().clear();
    }
```

I really don't know what to do because I'm new to JavaFX and Java Threading.

Comment: `Platform#runLater(Runnable)` executes the `Runnable` on the *JavaFX Application Thread*.

Comment: Using a `Task` and having all of the `Task` code in `Platform.runLater` makes the `Task` irrelevant.

Comment: The first thing you should do is separate your database logic from the other code. Then you use `Task` to query the DB and return the results using the `Task` `setOnSucceeded`. The second thing you should do is learn and master [`MVC`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx).

Comment: You linked to old documentation. Oracle moved JavaFX to an open-source project named OpenJFX, now co-led by Gluon and Oracle. Use the OpenJFX.io web site for current info. Current version of Javadoc is [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/22/).

Comment: IMO: The name, `runLater`, is one of many tricks in Java that trip up beginners. It _should_ be called, `runOnUIThread`. The reason why they put "later" in the name is, if you call `Platform.runLater(task)` _from_ the UI thread, then the `task` won't be performed until after the UI has completely finished handling the current event. (I.e., it won't be performed until "later.") If you call `runLater` from any other thread though, then the word "later" loses its meaning altogether. The `task` that you submit in that case will be performed by the UI thread, _concurrently_ with the calling thread.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Technically, the task will be run later, regardless of from which thread the method was called.

Comment: @VGR, if some "background" thread calls `Platform.runLater(r)` there is no _guarantee_ that the `r.run()` call won't be completed before the background thread begins to execute its very next statement. But, when some function `f` running on the UI thread calls `runLater(r)`, it absolutely _is_ guaranteed that the `r.run()` call won't even begin until some time after the `f` call has returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for doing time-consuming operations in a thread which is not the JavaFX application thread is that they would delay the processing of JavaFX events, including rendering scenes and processing mouse and keyboard input.

[Platform.runLater](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/22/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)) exists specifically for the purpose of running a task in the JavaFX application thread.  Using it to update your scene (which is what clearDataResultHolder() and dataResultHolder.getChildren().addAll(getArrayOfUserAsNode()) do) is correct.

However, calling Thread.sleep in the JavaFX application thread is detrimental.  That is what is freezing your application.

Creating a new thread based on a Task that does long-running operations is good, because that new thread is not the JavaFX application thread and will not hang the application thread.  You should be executing Thread.sleep in that task *before* calling Platform.runLater:

```
@Override
protected Void call() throws Exception {
    // Does the time-consuming work in this background thread,
    // NOT in the application thread.
    /* Simulate loading */
    Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);

    // Updates the user interface in the JavaFX application thread,
    // because updating it in this background thread is not allowed.
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        clearDataResultHolder();
        dataResultHolder.getChildren().addAll(getArrayOfUserAsNode());
    });
    return null;
}
```

If you were actually performing database operations, instead of just calling Thread.sleep, the code structure would be the same:  do the work in the Task’s thread, then call Platform.runLater to update the scene with the data you’ve retrieved.